# Joda-Time ignoring locale on en-US server

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to convert my string dates to timestamp.
In my pt-BR machine everything works fine. However, on an en-US server Joda ignores the custom locale.

On my laptop (Windows 8 pt-BR):

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
dateFormatter.parseLocalDate("13-Out-14").toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
```

This code runs flawlessly. The word for October in portuguese is Outubro.

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
dateFormatter.parseLocalDate("13-Oct-14").toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
```

The code above works fine as well. The JVM recognizes the new locale and converts the date.
However, when I try to run the first piece of code on a Windows Server 2012 en-US I get an exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "13-Out-14" is malformed at "Out-14"
  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:854)
  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:798)
  at br.com.luminiti.pro.service.DataUtil.dataStringToLong(DataUtil.java:155)
```

And if I change Out to Oct it converts with no problem. So it seems the JVM is using the language of the machine itself.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible it's because US dates aren't in that format? US dates are `MM/dd/yy` format usually.

Comment: @Zymus: No, because the OP is using a specific format...

Comment: Does the Windows Server machine have that locale installed?

Comment: I gonna check this. But my laptop should have the en-US locale installed as well, right?

Comment: Yes. My language is added. The Windows display language is available to download, but keyboard layout, date, time and number formatting is set already.

Comment: I think you misunderstood Jon Skeet's question. You should do something like `for ( Locale x : Locale.getAvailableLocales() ) System.out.println(x);` and see if it prints `pt_BR` anywhere.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, oh sorry. I ran this and I have the pt_BR locale on the server. In fact I have all these locales on the WinServer. http://pastebin.com/iPyX1A6S

Comment: By any chance, in your full source code, do you create a similar `DateTimeFormatter` with the same pattern **before** you set the locale?

Comment: @rcorreia The problem is the uppercase `O` in `Out`. Change to `out` and your code runs on my machine. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27002964/642706) below. You claim that the very same code runs on your laptop (Windows 8 pt-BR). Can you confirm that, double-checking that you have the exact same input string with an uppercase `O`?

Comment: @BasilBourque I can confirm that it works with `Out` on my machine. So no, the problem is not the uppercase O.

Comment: Can you run `System.out.println( Arrays.toString(DateTimeUtils.getDateFormatSymbols(new Locale("pt","BR")).getShortMonths()))` on your laptop and on the server and see if there are any differences? Perhaps lowercase month names as BasilBourque believes?

Comment: @BasilBourque Surprisingly, I think you are right. On my pt_BR machine I've got this answer: [Jan, Fev, Mar, Abr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Ago, Set, Out, Nov, Dez, ]. On the server, I've got this: [jan, fev, mar, abr, mai, jun, jul, ago, set, out, nov, dez, ]. Why this is happening? Why the difference on two different OS (and no so different, because both are Windows).

Comment: @rcorreia What version of Joda-Time?

Comment: @BasilBourque I am using 2.5.

Comment: What version of Java exactly do you have on each of the machines? Is it the JRE or JDK, which version and which maker (Oracle, other)? Joda Time takes the month names from the Java implementation when using the ISO chronology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Uppercase `O` Is Problem

The expected *abbreviated* name for October in Portuguese is `out`, not `Out`.

To demonstrate, this code in Joda-Time 2.5:

```
System.out.println( "October in Portuguese: " + DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MMM-yy" ).withLocale( locale_ptBR ).print( new DateTime( 2014 , 10 , 13 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ) );
```

…outputs a lowercase `o`:

```
October in Portuguese: 13-out-14
```

➥ So, change your input string from `13-Out-14` to `13-out-14` and your code works.

## Month Names Abbreviated

See what abbreviated month names are expected by Joda-Time:

```
Locale locale_ptBR = new Locale( "pt" , "BR" );  // Portuguese in Brazil.
System.out.println( "Short months for locale : " + locale_ptBR + Arrays.toString( org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getDateFormatSymbols( locale_ptBR ).getShortMonths() ) );

Locale locale_frCA = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;  // Québec.
System.out.println( "Short months for locale : " + locale_frCA + Arrays.toString( org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getDateFormatSymbols( locale_frCA ).getShortMonths() ) );

Locale locale_enUS = Locale.US;  // United States.
System.out.println( "Short months for locale : " + locale_enUS + Arrays.toString( org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getDateFormatSymbols( locale_enUS ).getShortMonths() ) );
```

When run with Joda-Time 2.5 in Java 8 Update 25 on a Mac (Mountain Lion) configured for United States (US).

```
Short months for locale : pt_BR [jan, fev, mar, abr, mai, jun, jul, ago, set, out, nov, dez, ]
Short months for locale : fr_CA [janv., févr., mars, avr., mai, juin, juil., août, sept., oct., nov., déc., ]
Short months for locale : en_US [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, ]
```

You can see how they vary in uppercase/lowercase, number of characters, and punctuation (`.`).

The rest of this answer addresses other issues with your Question’s code.

## Avoid Setting Default Locale

Calling [`Locale::setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault-java.util.Locale-) is a risky bad practice as it affects *all* the Java code running in *all* the threads of *all* the apps running in this *entire* Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Not only are you subverting the possible intention of other code to use the original default Locale, you are doing so *at runtime*, on-the-fly. You are changing it *while* that other code executes. Not good.

## Specify Locale

Rather than override the default Locale, specify your desired Locale. Call [`DateTimeFormatter::withLocale`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale(java.util.Locale)) to tell the formatter to apply a specific Locale when parsing or generating strings.

## Specify Time Zone

The code in the Question fails to account for the issue of time zone. Time zone is crucial for parsing and determining a date. In example code below, try swapping out the time zone applied to the formatter to see very different results.

If omitted, you get the JVM’s current default time zone applied. Such implicit use of the current default means your code's behavior may vary at runtime on various machines.

To specify a time zone, call `withZone`.

Use proper [time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Never use the 3 or 4 letter codes that are neither standardized nor unique.

## No Need For Local Date

No need for a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) in this particular case. Doing so should work, but keeping it in [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects might be simpler.

## Example Code

Example code in Joda-Time 2.5.

```
DateTimeZone zoneSaoPaulo = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Sao_Paulo" );
DateTimeZone zoneNewYork = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTimeZone zoneLosAngeles = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" );

Locale locale_ptBR = new Locale( "pt" , "BR" );
Locale locale_enUS = new Locale( "en" , "US" );

DateTimeFormatter formatter_ptBR = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MMM-yy" ).withLocale( locale_ptBR ).withZone( zoneSaoPaulo );
DateTimeFormatter formatter_enUS = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MMM-yy" ).withLocale( locale_enUS ).withZone( zoneSaoPaulo );  // Try swapping out this time zone to see very different results.

DateTime dateTime_ptBR = formatter_ptBR.parseDateTime( "13-out-14" ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();  // Month must be lowercase for Portuguese, "out" not "Out".
DateTime dateTime_enUS = formatter_enUS.parseDateTime( "13-Oct-14" ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();  // The call to "withTimeAtStartOfDay" is not necessary as it is the default when parsing date-only. I would include it to be self-documenting of our intention.

long millis_ptBR = dateTime_ptBR.getMillis();
long millis_enUS = dateTime_enUS.getMillis();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateTime_ptBR : " + dateTime_ptBR );
System.out.println( "dateTime_ptBR : " + formatter_ptBR.print( dateTime_ptBR ) );
System.out.println( "dateTime_ptBR : " + DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( locale_ptBR ).print( dateTime_ptBR ) );
System.out.println( "millis_ptBR : " + millis_ptBR );

System.out.println( "dateTime_enUS : " + dateTime_enUS );
System.out.println( "dateTime_enUS : " + formatter_enUS.print( dateTime_enUS ) );
System.out.println( "dateTime_enUS : " + DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( locale_enUS ).print( dateTime_enUS ) );
System.out.println( "millis_enUS : " + millis_enUS );

System.out.println( "UTC : " + dateTime_ptBR.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run.

```
dateTime_ptBR : 2014-10-13T00:00:00.000-03:00
dateTime_ptBR : 13-out-14
dateTime_ptBR : Segunda-feira, 13 de Outubro de 2014 00h00min00s BRT
millis_ptBR : 1413169200000

dateTime_enUS : 2014-10-13T00:00:00.000-03:00
dateTime_enUS : 13-Oct-14
dateTime_enUS : Monday, October 13, 2014 12:00:00 AM BRT
millis_enUS : 1413169200000

UTC : 2014-10-13T03:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: "Time zone is crucial for parsing and determining a date" - no it's not. Not if you stick to `LocalDate`, which is a more suitable data type for information which is just a date. The time zone is important if you *do* use `DateTime`, but if you're just parsing a date to a `LocalDate`, there's no logically no time zone in either the source data or the result. The call to `toDateTimeAtStartOfDay` (if actually required) should have a time zone instead, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet But we cannot stick to LocalDate in the case of this question. Note this third line of code in the Question's examples: `toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();`. The author's goal is to get the the count of milliseconds since epoch. So we must use DateTime, and so time zone *is* crucial in this Question and Answer.

Comment: That doesn't mean it needs to be parsed as a date time, nor does it make your statement that dates must be parsed with a time zone correct - indeed it could confuse someone who reads your answer but *does* only need a date. I think it's much clearer to parse the value as a LocalDate (given that that is the information in the string) and then apply the time zone afterwards, in the toDateTimeAtStartOfDay.

Comment: @BasilBourque Ok... so that's the deal. There were two problems. First one: Yes, in my machine Java expects a capital letter, on server not. Second one: I changed the Locale.setDefault to formatter.withLocale. I was using this before, but with Locale.forLanguageTag("pt_BR"). Like you said, the right way is new Locale("pt", "BR"). Now my code works on my laptop and on the server even if the first char is O or o. Thank you so much for your help. Thank you too Jon Skeet and RealSkeptic.